# Пунктуация. Насколько "сразу" читается предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

> **АП**: А как ты относишься к такой новой погремушке, как глобализм?
>
> **ИИ:** Плохо к этому отношусь. ***Считаю, что как общая мировая душа, к
>   сожалению, невозможна, так невозможна и общая мировая культура — да и
>   зачем это нужно?***

Закрывать ли запятую после "мировая культура"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считаю, что как, к сожалению, невозможна общая мировая душа, так невозможна общая мировая культура, — да и кому это нужно!

Comment: Лучше добавить союз "и": _так невозможна **и** общая мировая культура_...